# Function does not take 1 arguments when passing this into it

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm trying to pass an instance of **this** (the instance in question being the GameEngine class) into my PlayerBrain.run method which takes a GameEngine * const argument corresponding to what **this** is. I'm curious as to what would cause such an error to be thrown in this case, especially when there are no alternative function definitions for run() or anything like that. PlayerBrain is its own class, not descending from anything. So there's no alternative definitions to run that might cause problems. Here's the relevant code:

All public methods in PlayerBrain.h

```
#pragma once
#include "GameEngine.h"
#include "Species.h"
#include "Neuron.h"
#include "Genome.h"
#include "GenePool.h"
#include "Gene.h"
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;

class PlayerBrain {
private:
    int popSize;
    int stalenessThreshold;
    int timeoutConstant;
    int currentTimeout;
    int maxNodes;
    int farthestDistance;
    bool buttons[6]; // JASON - shoot, left, right, up, down, jump in that order
    GenePool p;

    bool fileExists(string filename);
    bool fitnessAlreadyMeasured();
    void nextGenome();
    void evaluateCurrent(Genome * g);
    void evaluateNetwork(vector<Neuron*> * network, vector<int> inputs);
    void loadPool(string filename);
    double sigmoid(double sum);
    vector<int> getInputs();
    Genome templateGenome();
    void pressAKey();
    void unPressAKey();
    vector<INPUT *> oldbuttons;

public:
    PlayerBrain();
    void intialize();
    void run(GameEngine const *);
    void close();
};
```

The actual implementation in its .cpp

```
 void PlayerBrain::run(GameEngine const * g) {
    Genome * current = p.getCurrentGenome();
    int xPos = 0;
    int bossLives = 0;
    double fitness;
    double timeoutBonus;

    unPressAKey();

    if ((p.getCurrentFrame() % 5) == 0)
        evaluateCurrent(current);

    pressAKey();

    xPos = g->getXPosAckVar();

    bossLives = g->getBossLivesAckVar();

    if (xPos > farthestDistance) { farthestDistance = xPos; currentTimeout = timeoutConstant; }
    currentTimeout--;
    timeoutBonus = p.getCurrentFrame() / 4;

    if ((currentTimeout + timeoutBonus) <= 0) { 
        fitness = (farthestDistance - (p.getCurrentFrame() / 2)) + 2000 * bossLives; 
        if (fitness == 0) { fitness = -1; }
        current->setFitness(fitness);

        if (fitness > p.getMaxFitness()) { p.setMaxFitness(fitness); }
        p.setCurrentSpecies(0);
        p.setCurrentGenome(0);
        while (fitnessAlreadyMeasured()) { nextGenome(); }
    }
    p.setCurrentFrame(p.getCurrentFrame() + 1);
}
```

The function call in GameEngine.cpp`

```
while (true)
    {
           ......//irrelevant stuff
            if (tickTimeNow > tickTimeTrigger)
                {
                if (dTimeTrigger > m_PaintTimeTrigger)
                {
                    ....
                    brain->run(this);
                    ....
                }
                else Sleep(1);
            }
            else WaitMessage();
        }
    }
```

The error I get is as follows:
Error   C2660   'PlayerBrain::run': function does not take 1 arguments

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting? Is PlayerBrain derived from some other class which has `run` method?

Comment: Edited my opening comment to answer your question but to save you the trouble, I'm getting "PlayerBrain::run function does not take 1 arguments" with error code C2660. And PlayerBrain is its own distinct class. It doesn't descend from anything or derive from anything.

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean `GameEngine const *`?

Comment: Under 99% of circumstances yes, but when I highlight (this) in Visual Studio it tells me "GameEngine * const this". I was trying to match the parameter to what it was saying which is why it makes no sense. I'll try changing it up to see if it changes anything. EDIT: It didn't.

Comment: Did `run` at some point in your development have a different number of arguments?  If so, are you using precompiled headers?

Comment: @ThomasVarney Again: Please prepare a [MCVE] that everyone can reproduce your error.

Comment: Paul, it did indeed have a different number of arguments, but I'm not using any precompiled headers.

Comment: Is there some kind of polymorphism going on here? What is the type of `brain`? As has been said before `GameEngine * const` and `GameEngine const *` are different types, when inheritance is involved this can lead to surprising results. It also might be a good idea to make your class `final` or `run()` `virtual`.

Comment: Basically, the declaration of `PlayerBrain::run` that you show here is not the same declaration that the compiler sees. You'll have to figure out why. My guess would be, you have a stale copy of the header lying around somewhere, and that is the header that ends up being included.